# Making an insert() method that keeps an ordered array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, comparable

I'm attempting to make an `insert()` method that keeps an ordered array still ordered using the `compareTo` method (no sorting algorithms, just using `compareTo`). 
It works when I do `list.insert(dd)` to `list.instert(aa)` but it doesn't work for `list.instert(dd)` to `list.insert(aa)` and I know why but do not know how to fix it. The `insert` method is in the second class.

Again I'm trying to make the `insert()` method keep an ordered array already ordered.
So for example with:

```
int[] Array = {1,2,6,7,9};
Array.insert(3);
Array.insert(8);
System.out.println(Array); // should print out 1,2,3,6,7,8,9
```

At-least if I was working with integers. In the code below I'm dealing with courses.

**Course:**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.*;

class Course implements Comparable<Object>, Serializable {
    private String _prefix;
    private int _number;
    private String _department;
    private String _grade;

    public Course(String prefix, int number, String department, String grade) {
        _prefix = prefix;
        _number = number;
        _department = department;
        if (grade == null)
            _grade = "";
        else
            _grade = grade;
    }

    public Course(String prefix, int number, String Department) {
        this(prefix, number, Department, "");
    }

    public String getPrefix() {
        return _prefix;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return _number;
    }

    public String getDepartment() {
        return _department;
    }

    public String getGrade() {
        return _grade;
    }

    public void setGrade(String grade) {
        _grade = grade;
    }

    public boolean taken() {
        return !_grade.equals("");
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        boolean result = false;
        if (other instanceof Course) {
            Course otherCourse = (Course) other;
            if (_prefix.equals(otherCourse.getPrefix())
                    && _number == otherCourse.getNumber())
                result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        Course temp = (Course) o;

        if (_department.compareTo(temp.getDepartment()) == 0) {
            if (_number < temp.getNumber()) {
                return -1;
            } else if (_number > temp.getNumber()) {
                return 1;
            } else if (_number == temp.getNumber()) {
                if (_prefix.compareTo(temp.getPrefix()) == 0) {
                    return 0;
                } else if (_prefix.compareTo(temp.getPrefix()) == 1) {
                    return 1;
                } else if (_prefix.compareTo(temp.getPrefix()) == -1) {
                    return -1;
                }
            }

        } else if (_department.compareTo(temp.getDepartment()) > 0) {
            return 1;
        } else if (_department.compareTo(temp.getDepartment()) < 0) {
            return -1;
        }

        return 0;

    }

    public String toString() {
        String result = _prefix + " " + _number + ": " + _department;
        if (!_grade.equals(""))
            result += "  [" + _grade + "]";
        return result;
    }
}
```

**CourseList:**

```
class CourseList {
    private Course[] _courseList;
    private int _size = 0;

    public CourseList() {
        // setting the current size of the array to 0 since a list starts with 0
        // elements
        _courseList = new Course[_size];
    }

    public int size() {
        return _size;
    }

    public void insert(Course courseToInsert) {

        Course[] tempCourseList = new Course[_size + 1];

        if (_size == 0) // if size = 0
        {
            tempCourseList[0] = courseToInsert;
            _size++; // used to tell if we need to increment the size or not
        }

        else // if size > 0
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++) {

                if (courseToInsert.compareTo(_courseList[i]) == -1) // if less
                    // than
                {
                    tempCourseList[i] = courseToInsert;

                    for (int j = i; j < _size; j++) {
                        tempCourseList[j + 1] = _courseList[i];
                        i++;
                    }
                    _size++;
                }

                else {
                    if (i == _size - 1) {
                        tempCourseList[i + 1] = courseToInsert;
                        _size++;
                    }

                    /*
                     * else if (i < _size) { for (int j = i; j < _size; j++) {
                     * tempCourseList[j+1] = _courseList[j]; } }
                     */
                }
            }
        }

        _courseList = tempCourseList;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String stringToReturn = "Contents of List:\n\n";

        for (Course a : _courseList) {
            stringToReturn += a + "\n";
        }

        return stringToReturn;
    }
}
```

**Driver:**

```
public class Driver {
    public static Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CourseList list = new CourseList();

        Course ff = new Course("IEE", 380, "Engineering");
        Course a = new Course("EEE", 230, "Engineering");
        Course b = new Course("MAT", 150, "Liberal Arts");
        Course c = new Course("PHY", 150, "Liberal Arts");
        Course d = new Course("PHI", 304, "Liberal Arts");
        Course e = new Course("ECN", 214, "W.P. Carey");
        Course f = new Course("EEE", 120, "Engineering");

        Course aa = new Course("PHI", 304, "AAAAAA");
        Course bb = new Course("ECN", 214, "BBBBBB");
        Course cc = new Course("EEE", 120, "CCCCCC");
        Course dd = new Course("EEE", 120, "DDDDDD");

        // System.out.println( aa.compareTo(aa) );
        // System.out.println( aa.compareTo(bb) );
        // System.out.println( bb.compareTo(aa) );

        String bbb = "BBB";
        String aaa = "AAA";

        /*
         * list.insert(dd); list.insert(cc); // works list.insert(bb);
         * list.insert(aa);
         */

        list.insert(aa);
        list.insert(bb);
        /*
         * list.insert(cc); list.insert(dd);
         */

        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your comparison functions are checking `x.compareTo(y) == -1` and `x.compareTo(y) == 1` whereas the `Comparable` interface allows `compareTo` to return any integer.  You should be checking `< 0` and `> 0` instead of `== -1` and `== 1`.  Otherwise, your comparison function is non-transitive.

Comment: What is the output when the insert doesn't work?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at CourseList.insert(Driver.java:155)
    at Driver.main(Driver.java:249)

Comment: Basically _couseList[i] doesn't exist when I check to see if it's less than since i=0 but the size of _courseList is also 1.

Comment: @MikeSamuel my compareTo method returns -1, 1, & 0. Look at the first class.

Comment: The insert method of CourseList breaks when third element is being added, you are updating the _size variable after shifting the elements to right, so the outer loop is executing one more time and it is trying to write the last element outside the index of courseList array.

Comment: @AdamStaples, yes, but the problem is not the return value, but that it compares strings and assumes that `String.compareTo` only returns (-1, 0, 1) when `String.compareTo` can return values outside that range.

Comment: In addition to the above suggestions, during the insert, I noticed that you still keep on comparing values even after you have found the spot where to insert the value in the array. You should place a break after inserting.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to make your own method here, Arrays.binarySearch() will tell you where to put it.  So simply:

```
Course[] temp = new Course[_courseList.size()]
_courseList.toArray(temp);
_courseList.add(Math.abs(Arrays.binarySearch(temp,courseToInsert)) - 1,courseToInsert);
```

And you're done.  Don't reinvent the wheel, almost everything already exists in the libraries.  If you have java 1.8 you can remove the temp array too.

Comment: Assignment: 

"Order the courses first by department and then by course number. Then write a program that uses an ordered list to maintain a list of courses."

You canNOT use a built-in Java data structure for the ordered list. You can use either an array implementation or a linked list implementation."

Comment: nowhere in your post do you mention that you can't use libraries.